# How to do wrap text in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

```
 var serviceAddressTemplate = '<div class="grid-tooltip" tooltip="{{ row.entity.SPServiceRequest_address }}" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-append-to-body="true"><div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{ row.entity.SPServiceRequest_address }}</div></div>';
```

I am new to angularjs .
This is my code to wrap text in ui-grid but its not effecting in column.
Can any help me to do wrap content in cells in anguarjs.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following CSS code to allow text wrapping in uigrid

```
/* CSS to allow text wrapping */
.ui-grid-viewport .ui-grid-cell-contents {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal !important;
}

.ui-grid-row, .ui-grid-cell {
  height: auto !important;
}

.ui-grid-row div[role=row] {
  display: flex ;
  align-content: stretch;
}
/* End of CSS to allow text wrapping */
```